# SQL - Group By 2 fields, where Count is Greater than X

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to find the correct and efficient way to write this query.  For a sales data set, I want to isolate customers with more than 4 transactions in a given month, but with that, I want the details of the sale.

What've written so far is two volatile tables: T1) Details and T2) Count.  T1, puts all the details of the sales into a volatile table and T2 counts the transactions based on identifiers of Store, Date, Time, Trans_ID, Cashier and TotalSale (grouping).  Some transactions will show twice based on the details in T1, so I'm trying to eliminate the duplicates without removing the details.

My third query queries T1 against T2, where the Count in T2 is greater than 1.

I think this works, however, I'm not sure it's the most efficient way to run it as it takes hours to run this way.  Any input on changes I can make?  Code is pasted below:

```
create volatile table IC_DTL as
(
SELECT          DISTINCT
o.orgn_nm                                               REGION
,   o.str_org_nbr                                       STORE
,   d.sltrn_dt                                          SLS_DATE
,   cast(d.last_upd_ts as TIME)                         SLS_TIME
,   d.pos_rgstr_id                                      REGISTER
,   d.sltrn_id                                          TRANS_ID
,   dp.user_id                                          CASHIER_ID
,   d.sltrn_line_nbr                                    LINE_ITEM
,   i.sub_class_nbr                                     SUB_CLASS
,   i.item_sc_desc                                      SC_DESC
,   i.item_sku_nbr                                      SKU
,   i.item_desc                                         SKU_DESC
,   d.ITEM_QTY                                          QTY
,   d.EXT_RETL_AMT                                      EXT_RETAIL
,   st.grs_sls_amt                                      GROSS_SALE_AMT
,   pc.s_paymt_meth_desc                                PAYMT_METH
,   py.cardhldr_acct_nbr                                ACCT_NBR
FROM ALL MY TABLES (9 JOINS)

WHERE   MY CONDITIONS
)

WITH DATA
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

---

```
Create volatile table IC_COUNT as
(
select cashier_id, count(Trans_ID) as TOTAL
FROM IC_DETL
GROUP BY store, sls_date, sls_time, trans_id, cashier_id
,gross_sales_amt
)
WITH DATA
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

select *
from IC_DTL D
JOIN IC_COUNT C
ON C.CASHIER_ID = D.CASHIER_ID
WHERE D.TOTAL >= 2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Create index on volatile table and than run your query..index should be on your join condition.

Comment: I am utterly unable to follow your question.  You mention transactions by customer, and then are aggregating by cashier.  You mention 4 as a limit, but then the code has 2.  You mention month, but I see that nowhere in the queries.  Sample data and desired results might clarify what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Apologies, my edits to get the code in didn't match and I forgot to edit the section above the code.  To clarify:  ordering by cashier, with d.total >= 2.

Comment: the month/date range is in my where clause

Comment: also partition your table using cashier id ( or month) as then join ..as it will use partition elimination as well.

Comment: You probably don't need the `IC_COUNT` table, might be a `QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITITON BY store, sls_date, sls_time, trans_id, cashier_id
,gross_sales_amt >= 2` instead. But your code is still confusing, you `GROUP BY` multiple column, but join only on `CASHIER_ID `, this will join multiple rows. Btw, if this your actual `CREATE TABLE IC_DTL` it will be totally skewed and might need a lot of CPU if it's a `
SET` table

Comment: @DJDJ23 if you still wish to get help you should fix the above mentioned confusion in your question.